# PHP - is_readable() returns incorrect value

Tags: php, file, fopen, fread

I'm using script like this:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__)."/folder/file.ext"
if(is_readable($path)){
     $file = fread(fopen($path,"r"), filesize($path));
}else{
     //do something else if file can't be opened
}
```

And surprisingly it generates the following error:

```
Warning: fread() [function.fread]: Length parameter must be greater than 0
in /nfs/c10/h02/mnt/161920/domains/example.com/html/my-folder/file.php on line 16
```

I'm wondering why this happens. It happens only on some servers and on others it's fine. What are requirements to use `fread` successfully? File exists in that location.

Comment: Look up file_get_contents() instead of a hack where you don't close the file after reading it.

Comment: Your `filesize($path)` value is 0 or less than zero check the value by printing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone has said, filesize is probably 0.

Either use `file_get_contents` as suggested, or if you absolutely want/need to use `fread()`, you could get around it with the following on php 5.3+:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__)."/folder/file.ext"
if(is_readable($path)){
    $file = fread(fopen($path,"r"), filesize($path) ?: 1);
}else{
    //do something else if file can't be opened
}
```

Notice the `?: 1`? It's called a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). That says, use filesize if it evaluates to true (i.e. it's bigger than 0) or use 1.

Definitely not best practice but fun to point out.

Comment: Great :) Thanks so much! Now I see what is going on with it and thank you for this `?:` trick.

Comment: Read up on [PHP ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), it's a nifty feature!

Comment: Yes, I know this - I often use this but I'll go with `file_get_contents` because `?: 1` it looks like some unsafe cheat ((1) is it safe to give file 1 byte if it's 0? It can possibly cause further issues (2) why does it have 0? None of my files have 0 - unless it tried to load some hidden files, too because I'm doing `scandir` and I exclude only `.` and `..`, (3) even if file is empty - shouldn't it always have some size?).

Comment: I agree; I would use the semantically explicit method. To answer your questions though: (1) yes, i believe so, fread just wants to know how much to read, (2) no idea, but (3) it's not invalid: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_byte_file

Comment: Then perhaps some servers contain "zero byte" files and others don't. I'll test that with `file_get_contents` soon on client server and it will probably work fine :) Thanks so much for your answers! I'm marking this as accepted answer because it contains more information but both answers to this question are correct.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is empty, it can be read. But you cannot read 0 bytes with `fread`.

Empty file == filesize of 0.

For your usecase you could also use PHP's [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) function.

Comment: Great :) Thanks so much! Now I see what is going on with it.